# how to find Count of start_point to dest_point both are strings and not unique fields

Tags: mysql

My database contains the following fields

Mydb(id,startpoint,destpoint)

startpoint and destpoint are strings and not unique

My question is: How can i find count of  startpoint to destpoint (for ex dadar to washi count can be 4, kothrud to mgroad count can be 10,etc );

Some sample data

id   startpoint   destpoint

1    kothrud       jmrd
2    sangvi        kothrud
3    kothrud       jmrd
4    Yerwada       kothrud
5    kothrud       jmrd
6    sangvi        kothrud

now i want to write a query which will give me the following output based on the above data

kothrud jmrd      3
sangvi  kothrud   2
yerwada kothrud   1

for each pair of startpoint and destpoint it should give me the count as above

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are looking for:

```
Select startpoint,destpoint,count(*) from points group by startpoint,destpoint
```